# Structure question over Local/Remote Services, Broadcast Receivers, and Intent Services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm writing an android app that has a standard activity, but also needs to monitor incoming/outgoing calls and texts at all times. In addition, the app needs to notify users of information once a day without having the activity open. The information it notifies users of is stored in a database, so communication with the activity is not necessary.  I've been researching for a week and still can't decide how to go about doing this.  My instinct tells me I need a remote service that has a constantly running broadcast receiver, but every remote service example I see is overly complicated.  Could anyone help me better understand what steps I need to take? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My instinct tells me I need a remote service that has a constantly running broadcast receiver

Um, no. I say that, because:

- There is only one application, and so there is no need for a "remote" service
- A "service that has a constantly running broadcast receiver" is a really bad idea, as users will attack you with task killers and, even if they don't, Android will terminate your service eventually anyway as being a waste of space

Use `BroadcastReceivers` registered in your manifest for broadcasts that can occur at any time, as they will get control even if nothing else of your application is running. Use an `IntentService` for doing any "heavy lifting" that is needed by those `BroadcastReceivers`, as `BroadcastReceiver` get control (in `onReceive()`) on the main application thread and therefore should do as little work as possible. Also, use `AlarmManager` to signal a `BroadcastReceiver` (or, possibly, your `IntentService`) to raise a `Notification` for your once-daily event.

Also, please be advised that there is no way for you to "monitor...outgoing...texts", and that to "monitor...incoming...texts" requires you to use an undocumented capability of Android. While *probably* `android.provider.Telephony` will not be going away, you just need to be aware of the risk involved.